# Dynamic Cast Call Failed

Tags: swift, uitableview

My iOS app in swift crashes when i tap a tableview cell. This was all done programmatically. (except for a manual segue) When I tap a cell I get a Dynamic Cast Call Failed.

Does this have to do with CoreData, my segue or my tableview? The error only showed when I got the segue to work. Before the same code for the table and CoreData were used with tables and views created in Storyboard. (except for the `didSelectRowAtIndex`) Then everything worked. Unfortunately doing it through storyboard is not an option for the rest of the app.

Truly at a lost here. Can post more code if needed.

Thank you

This is the error message i get on crash.

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x1042679e0:  pushq  %rbp
0x1042679e1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x1042679e4:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x1042679e7:  je     0x104267a1e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x1042679e9:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x1042679f3:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x1042679f6:  jne    0x104267a1e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x1042679f8:  leaq   0xb5109(%rip), %rax
0x1042679ff:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x104267a02:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x104267a05:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x104267a10:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x104267a13:  je     0x104267a2d               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x104267a15:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x104267a19:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x104267a1c:  jne    0x104267a10               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x104267a1e:  leaq   0x36b3d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x104267a25:  movq   %rax, 0xb4a2c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x104267a2c:  int3   
0x104267a2d:  movq   %rdi, %rax
0x104267a30:  popq   %rbp
0x104267a31:  retq   
0x104267a32:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

---

This is my relevant code (i think)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier? == "update" {
            var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = myTodos[self.todoTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as NSManagedObject

            let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TodoViewController

            IVC.todoItem = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoItem") as String
            IVC.todoTime = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoTime") as NSDate

            IVC.existingTodo = selectedItem
        }
    }
```

---

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("update", sender: self)
        println("You selected a cell")

    }
```

---

Edit with corrected code:
The problem was caused by trying to pass the segue through a navigation controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier? == "update" {
            var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = myTodos[self.todoTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as NSManagedObject

            let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController

            //let tableVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as YourTableViewControllerClass
            let IVC: TodoViewController = navVC.viewControllers.first as TodoViewController


            IVC.todoItem = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoItem") as String
            IVC.todoTime = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoTime") as NSDate

            IVC.existingTodo = selectedItem
        }
    }
```

Update :

```
let IVC: TodoViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).viewControllers.first as TodoViewController
```

or

```
let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as TodoViewController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see four downcasts in your code:

```
var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = myTodos[self.todoTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as NSManagedObject
let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TodoViewController
IVC.todoItem = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoItem") as String
IVC.todoTime = selectedItem.valueForKey("todoTime") as NSDate
```

My guess is that the error is in one of the last 2 rows - however I suggest you to put a breakpoint at the first line and step through the code - this will allow you to find the row that actually generates the error.

Comment: it was the first one `let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TodoViewController`

Comment: [this is my actual problem explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327267/swift-dynamic-cast-failed-uipageviewcontroller)

Except that I have a navigation controller in the way. Either i get a down cast error, or I dont have my navigation bar. But it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

If your tableview controller was embedded in a UINavigationController, then segue.destinationViewController is a UINavigationController instance, not a TodoViewController instance.

You probably could have kept your navigation controller and replaced this line:

`let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as TodoViewController`

with this:

```
let IVC: TodoViewController = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as TodoViewController`
```

the .topViewController property of UINavigationController refers to the top of the navigation stack, which should be your TodoViewController

Comment: look at my final edit with the corrected code, it shows something similar.

Comment: Yes it does show something similar, and I'm glad you solved it, and I hope my answer adds some value to others with the same issue.

Comment: looking at my own code (from when I was just starting with all this) and comparing it with yours makes me realise that that piece of code could be optimised to look just like yours. Things I now do all the time, but I still use that piece of code without thinking about it :)